# What is the relationship between a task and a macro task in an EventLoop?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

When I was studying the event loop, neither the HTML standard nor the MDN mentioned the macrotask concept (just tasks and microtasks), but I saw them in some blogs. I wonder where the macro task comes from? And what is the relationship between the task and the macro task?

HTML Standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide/In_depth

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is no concept of **macro**-task anywhere in the HTML specs.
Though it's often used in informal texts (even among the [specs issues](https://github.com/whatwg/html/search?q=macro-task&type=Issues)) as a mean to distinguish clearly when we talk about *tasks* and not about *microtasks*.

Since *microtasks* are a subset of *task*, it can sometimes help to clearly distinguish.

**So "macro-task" --> "task" but not "microtask".**