# Where does the concept of macrotasks come from in the browser?

Tags: chromium, v8, event-loop, task-queue, libuv

In many articles about the browser's event loop, the concept of macrotasks and microtasks is mentioned. But I looked at the description of event loops in the HTML spec, where there is no concept of macrotasks, only two types of tasks (tasks and microtasks). Why does everyone call this task a macro task? Where does the concept of macrotasks come from?

A long time ago, I accidentally came across an article explaining the origin of macro tasks. It said that the term "macro task" was used in the variables that implement the event loop in the Chromium source code. I cannot confirm the accuracy of this article, and I can no longer find the article. Therefore, I would like to confirm whether the article is correct, and whether the term "macro task queue" is used in the Chromium source code. If you have any relevant information, please provide specific links. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with HTML or the DOM; it's all JavaScript runtime stuff.

Comment: It's probably just that "macro" is the opposite of "micro".

Comment: @Pointy OP is still asking about the HTML5 spec in particular. If you find JS runtime documentation introducing the term, please write an answer

Comment: It was just "tasks" until microtasks were added. Talking about tasks vs mircotasks seems misleading when you want to say they are different.

Comment: I don't know why you keep adding Chromium and libuv as tags when you are interested in browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128836/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-task-and-a-macro-task-in-an-eventloop

Comment: Bergi as far as I know (I'll go back and look) the JS spec is pretty vague about "jobs" and how they're scheduled. However I still feel like this is a  JavaScript runtime mechanism, as one has to deal with the task queue behavior in Node or any other non-browser environment.

Comment: @Pointy I agree, it's just that HTML5 describes one such runtime, and in particular introduces the term "microtask"

Comment: @VLAZ A long time ago, I saw an article explaining the origin of macro tasks. It said that the term "macro task" was used in the variables that implement the event loop in the Chromium source code. So I added this label. Also, the browser's event loop is based on libuv, so I added libuv. I am very sorry to have caused misunderstandings, but I really hope that the seniors can help me solve my troubles.

Comment: @Aalpha "*A long time ago, I saw an article explaining the origin of macro tasks. It said that the term "macro task" was used in the variables that implement the event loop in the Chromium source code.*" - if you already know this, and are just asking for confirmation of this story (or even just to dig up that old article), it is crucial info that you should state this in your question. Please [edit] it accordingly.

Comment: @Aalpha "*the browser's event loop is based on libuv*" - no. Maybe one particular browser implementation, but not every browser. You don't seem to be asking about the usage of the term in Chromium only though, or are you?

Comment: "*the browser's event loop is based on libuv,*" other way around. Browsers have existed for over three decades. JS has existed for just shy of three decades (95-ish). The initial release of libuv was in 2013. And it was developed with Node.js in mind.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I am very sorry for the inaccurate description. The browser mentioned here refers to Chromium.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, thank you very much for the suggestions. I have already added the description again.

Comment: For HTML, there are indeed only task and microtask concepts, which are constructs used by the specs authors to describe a set of actions an User Agent has to perform. There is no direct relation with EcmaScript, except that some of these tasks may run scripts, or that some ES hooks like HostEnqueuePromiseJob will queue a microtask. I personally (and I'm not the only one) fight against the use of this "macrotask" term, because it's too easy to confuse between both (i vs a) and because it make it look like microtasks aren't tasks, and it misses the distinction between tasks and callbacks.

Comment: Now it may be noted that this is a specs concept. Very useful to describe the browsers' behavior, but that doesn't necessarily match with the reality of the implementations. For instance it seems that Safari doesn't really have a concept of task that matches the HTML one. And then nodejs has its own event loop logic and structs that don't really match with what's a *task* or a *microtask* (e.g. `nextTick`). And there, they do use the term `macrotask queue`, at least [in their docs](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/understanding-setimmediate) (though it seems it's the timers queue)

Comment: @Kaiido If you say that microtasks are tasks, then what do you call the tasks that aren't microtasks?

Comment: They're just task. If what matters is how they're queued, then they're global tasks, or element tasks, or timer tasks or whatever task source they're from that matters at that point.

Comment: @Kaiido I guess in my mental model a macrotask is any task that ends in a microtask checkpoint, i.e. has all microtasks processed before another task of the same kind (task source) can occur. Doesn't the spec have a term for that?

Comment: @Bergi, No. And actually that's part of my point: you missed that callbacks aren't *tasks*. For instance between two `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks you will have a microtask checkpoint. So that should have been part of *your* definition of a *macrotask*. But it's not even a task, (Noam Rosenthal is working on making the whole update the rendering a task, but each callback in it are still just callbacks, even though they'll empty the list of microtasks between them). So just like there is no word for any other dogs than Husky, there is no word for any other tasks than microtask.

Comment: If we want to talk generally about the task that have been queued in one of the task-sources, and thus could get picked up at the beginning of the event loop processing, we say "a queued task".

Comment: @Kaiido Ah I see what you're getting at, I would indeed have expected each raf callback to be called from a separate task. Possibly with stricter requirements on processing order, like exhausting the task queue from that source before switching to other tasks. And I guess that would have worked as well, it's not really different behaviour from the JS point of view. But it does matter for the spec text, and I'll change my mental model to what the official terms describe. Thanks!